# Passing a C# byte array to LuaInterface

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

I have a byte array in my C# code that I need to pass into a LuaInterface instance. I can use pack() in Lua, pass the resulting string to C# and convert it with `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`, but going the other way doesn't seem to work.

Is there a simple solution?  I'm hoping I can avoid assigning the byte array to a global value.

**Edit**:
I tried a few new things this morning.  I tried using `LuaInterface.GetFunction()`, and everything works until it hits `lua_pushstring()` in LuaDLL.cpp.  At this point the C# string is converted to a char* via `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi().ToPointer()`.  It looks like this function expects a null terminated string, and my string's first byte is 0 so I get an empty string in my lua code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally traced it down to a the call to `::lua_pushstring()` in lapi.c.  It called `strlen()` on the char* passed in.  Since my first byte of data was 0, it returned 0.  There is an alternate call, `lua_pushlstring`, that accepts the size of the string as an argument.  Changing to call this function fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your byte array with [System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx) to get a string that can be passed to Lua.

Comment: I tried this initially, except with UTF8 encoding.  The problem is passing the data into Lua at that point.  I have to call the lua function via lua.DoString("parse(_data_)");  The string formatting doesn't like the null characters.